# How to use zoomToMapObject when using lat and long for putting locations on map

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, ammap

I am working on `amcharts map` in `angular`. I am binding locations using on `lat` and `long`, I don't have countries `id` rather have location name. I want to zoom specific location using `zoomToMapObject`.

I have dropdown, when I select one country from it, I want to zoom that.

This is my `object` of `locationData`

```
{
    "dId": 28046,
    "lat": 33.8627681,
    "long": -117.8870831,
    "loc": "Fullerton  CA"
    "color":"red"
},
    {
    "dId": 25535,
    "lat": 31.5649775,
    "long": -110.2591639,
    "loc": "Sierra Vista  AZ"
     "color":"yellow"
},
    "dId": 31222,
    "lat": 33.4308114,
    "long": -70.7828727,
    "loc": "Pudahuel  Metropolitana"
     "color":"green"
},
{
    "dId": 23280,
    "lat": 36.1676717,
    "long": -94.1298177,
    "loc": "Springdale  AR"
    "color":"red"
},
```

When I select dropdown, In `SelectCountry` how can I get my code work. These all variables are returning `undefined`, hence `zoomToMapObject` not working

```
public mapCountry_selected(country)
{
   setTimeout( () => {  
     this.mapChart.zoomToGeoPoint({latitude:country.lat,longitude:country.long},17,true)
   }, 100);
}
```

This is my code

```
public locationMap()
{
    this.mapChart = am4core.create("productsMap", am4maps.MapChart);
    this.mapChart .geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
    this.mapChart .projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
    this.polygonSeries = this.mapChart .series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    this.polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
    this.polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
    this.polygonSeries.calculateVisualCenter = true;

    let imageSeries = this.mapChart .series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
  
    var place = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
    place.nonScaling = true;
    place.propertyFields.latitude = "lat";
    place.propertyFields.longitude = "long";

    imageSeries.data=this.locationData;
    var circle = place.createChild(am4core.Circle);
    circle.propertyFields.fill = "color";  
  
    imageSeries.heatRules.push({
     "target": circle,
     "property": "radius",
     "min": 3,
     "max": 10,
     "dataField": "value",
    })
}
```

**Edit1:**

I am showing circle for every location(`"target": circle`) with three colors green, yellow, red. Now after adding `true` point 2nd and 3rd solved(from my comment). I need highlight/popover location after selecting one from dropdown so user can directly will come know this location I have selected as there are many locations around each other.

**Edit2:**

Map after selecting location from dropdown

[image]

Comment: `zoomToMapObject` is especially useful using event listeners. However since in your country data you already have latitude and longitude, you could zoom to a location using `this.mapChart.zoomToGeoPoint({latitude:country.lat,longitude:country.long},17)` where 17 is the zoom level. Is it that you want to specifically extract the map object from the amcharts api in order to zoom or would this work for you instead?

Comment: the updated answer now uses `zoomToMapObject`, I have created pseudo-ids and included a working example

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. As you have added `function(place)` on my data, I have all my data in `this.locationData`, not plain JSON so adding `.map(function(place)` should be done on `this.locationData`.

Comment: I assumed, this.locationData had an array of objects as shown in the example so yes, you can update as `this.locationData.map(function(place) .....and the rest of the code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Initial Response for Question Revision 1

### Recommended Approach

Based on what information you have available it may be easier to consider using the [zoomToGeoPoint](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapchart/#zoomToGeoPoint_method) method available on the MapChart object eg

```js
//assuming the selected country is as follows
var country = { 
    "dId": 23280,
    "lat": 36.1676717,
    "long": -94.1298177,
    "loc": "Springdale  AR",
    "color":"red",
};
this.mapChart.zoomToGeoPoint({latitude:country.lat,longitude:country.long},17)
```

where `17` is your desired zoom level. `zoomToMapObject` is especially useful when handling chart events.

### More specific to your question

However, if you would like to use the [zoomToMapObject](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapchart/#zoomToMapObject_method) method, Based on your example the following approach could be considered.

For each data point in your dataset, and using the initial data stored in `am4geodata_worldLow` which has the "id" (eg. extracting the id for the first `am4geodata_worldLow.features[0].id`) for each polygon, you could determine for each country/place using the lat/lng coordinates which is closest to the center of each polygon.

In the `MapChart` object you have stored in `this.mapChart` there are multiple series (vaguely considered as layers) which you would have to check for polygon or MapObjects. These can be extracted using the following:

```
var mapPolygons = this.mapChart.series.values.flatMap(function(seriesItem){return seriesItem.mapPolygons.values;});
```

You could then build a data structure mapping each of your custom country/places to the ids available in the map (for eg an object `{"your-country-id":mapPolygonObject}`)

For each `mapPolygon` you can extract coordinate points using

```
var coordinates = mapPolygon.points[0][0]; //returns an array of x,y coordinates
//eg
coordinates = 
[{"x":691.2713756097037,"y":137.68935508639663},{"x":691.2544487420046,"y":137.69150482342081},{"x":691.2544487420046,"y":137.67239542245633},{"x":691.2695833531237,"y":137.6702455263596}];
```

You could then find the [center/centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of this polygon using these points as bounds and then for each of your country points you would find the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the polygon center point and your country. The shortest distance could assume that this country is associated with this point. Considerations may be made for distance (NB. Since you are working with coordinates, be sure to consider to 5 decimal points at least) as 50,000 miles (please observe your coordinate system for ways to convert lat/lng distances to metres/miles) may mean these are different places.

You could then extract the ids and build your map object for use later in your script. This may be time consuming and compute intensive and ideally would be better if you did this before had and stored the necessary references to be used later.

### Another Approach to search for ids

Moreover, if you had the country ids, then this would be simpler search as denoted below:

```
//assuming the selected country is as follows
var country = { 
    "dId": 23280,
    "lat": 36.1676717,
    "long": -94.1298177,
    "loc": "Springdale  AR",
    "color":"red",
};
//for this example I am extracting the country id from the object,it would be ideal to have it otherwise
//NB. country ids are also available in the `am4geodata_worldLow` used to initialize the map
var countryId = country.loc.split(" ")[1]; //this would return the country code - 'AR' 

//we will now search the created chart for mapObjects with this id
//this will give us an array of map objects/polygons with the id if found
var possibleMapObjects = this.mapChart.series.values.map(function(seriesItem){
    return seriesItem.getPolygonById(countryId)
}).flat();


if(possibleMapObjects.length > 0){
   // we have found a map object
   var countryMapObject = possibleMapObjects[0]; //taking the first item of array
   //now we can zoom to map object
   //the 3rd parameter true implies centering the map
   this.mapChart.zoomToMapObject(countryMapObject,17,true)
}
```

## Initial Response for Question Revision 2 (Edit1)

Based on the updated code, I noticed a few issues, I was unable to see markers on your map so i made a few modifications. Also, the modifications now allow you to retrieve marker/map objects by id as I have augmented the data with the id you have used please see updated code below.

I have created a dropdown/select node to simulate the onchange event, in the callback/event handler, `onCountryChange` you will see how we can retrieve a marker by it's new pseudo-id that we specified and call actions (I will open a popup) according to the [Documented MapImage API](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapimage/)

```js
locationData = [

  {
    "dId": 28046,
    "lat": 33.8627681,
    "long": -117.8870831,
    "loc": "Fullerton  CA",
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "dId": 25535,
    "lat": 31.5649775,
    "long": -110.2591639,
    "loc": "Sierra Vista  AZ",
    "color": "yellow"
  },
  {
    "dId": 31222,
    "lat": 33.4308114,
    "long": -70.7828727,
    "loc": "Pudahuel  Metropolitana",
    "color": "green"
  },
  {
    "dId": 23280,
    "lat": 36.1676717,
    "long": -94.1298177,
    "loc": "Springdale  AR",
    "color": "red"
  },
].map(function(place) {
  place.id = place.dId;
  return place;
});

this.mapChart = am4core.create("productsMap", am4maps.MapChart);
this.mapChart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
this.mapChart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
this.polygonSeries = this.mapChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
this.polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
this.polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
this.polygonSeries.calculateVisualCenter = true;

let imageSeries = this.mapChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());

var place = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
place.nonScaling = true;
place.propertyFields.latitude = "lat";
place.propertyFields.longitude = "long";

imageSeries.data = locationData;
var circle = place.createChild(am4core.Circle);
circle.propertyFields.fill = "color";
/// code below made circles visible and used value in {loc} / location name as tooltiptext
circle.width = 20;
circle.height = 20;
circle.nonScaling = false;
circle.tooltipText = "{loc}";
circle.horizontalCenter = "middle";
circle.verticalCenter = "bottom";

var circle2 = imageSeries.mapImages.template.createChild(am4core.Circle);
circle2.radius = 3;
circle2.propertyFields.fill = "color";


circle2.events.on("inited", function(event){
  animateBullet(event.target);
})


function animateBullet(circle) {
    var animation = circle.animate([{ property: "scale", from: 1, to: 5 }, 
 
   {property: "opacity", from: 1, to: 0 }], 1000, am4core.ease.circleOut);
    animation.events.on("animationended", function(event){
      animateBullet(event.target.object);
    })
}

imageSeries.heatRules.push({
  "target": circle,
  "property": "radius",
  "min": 3,
  "max": 10,
  "dataField": "value",
});

//just initializing the ui (you have already done this in angular)
var ddlPlaceChooser = document.getElementById("ddlPlaceChooser");

locationData.map(function(location) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = location.id;
    option.innerText = location.loc;
    return option;
  })
  .forEach(function(option) {
    ddlPlaceChooser.appendChild(option)
  })

function onCountryChange(event) {

  //however you retrieve the selected id
  var placeId = ddlPlaceChooser.selectedOptions[0].value;
  //retrieve map object
  var mapObject = imageSeries.getImageById(placeId);
  //zoom to map object
  mapChart.zoomToMapObject(mapObject, 17, true);
  //optionally open popup with message of choice
  mapObject.openModal("You choose me!")
  //mapObject.openPopup("You choose me!")



}

ddlPlaceChooser.addEventListener('change', onCountryChange)
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="placeChooser">Choose Place</label>
  <select id="ddlPlaceChooser" name="placeChooser"></select>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="productsMap"></div>
```

Comment: I used `zoomToGeoPoint`. Can you please check these points

_1)_ After `zoom` how can I know which place I zoom-in like `border/animation/highlight` beause there are many location/circle are there on map
_2)_ After one `zoom` if I select another location nothing happens
_3)_ Is there any way I do searched location in `Center`

Comment: I tried to replicate your example with what was posted, I only see a map with countries in green no points/circle. 1) you could add a map marker/pin/circle with popover and highlights [link](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/) before or after you select each location instead of trying to  highlight polygons you don't have id's for. 2) please share code on how you are calling or have attached the SelectCountry method to events/html. 3) You may add `true` as the third parameter eg `this.mapChart.zoomToGeoPoint({latitude:country.lat,longitude:country.long},17,true)`

Comment: I have update my question, data and select event code. please check. Thank you.

Comment: This example is great but no sure how can I do it on selection 
could you please check. I just need little difference that's all. https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-with-pulsating-bullets/

Comment: I updated the response , please see edit along with working example and comments in the example

Comment: I just saw that you had asked about the pulsating bullets, I've updated the working example to include this. You can go ahead and mark this as your accepted answer.

Comment: I have used `zoomToGeoPoint`. My dropdown is of Bootstrap so I am unable to use zoomToObject and consequently openModal not going to work for me. Now now  idea how to highlight/animate the selected location circle. If you can suggest something inside mapCountry_selected will be great. Check updated image in question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it

```
public selectedLocation(country)
  {  
    var imageSeries = this.mChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
    var mapImage = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
    var mapMarker = mapImage.createChild(am4core.Sprite);
    mapMarker.path = "M4 12 A12 12 0 0 1 28 12 C28 20, 16 32, 16 32 C16 32, 4 20 4 12 M11 12 A5 5 0 0 0 21 12 A5 5 0 0 0 11 12 Z";
    mapMarker.width = 5;
    mapMarker.height = 3;
    mapMarker.scale = 0.02;
    mapMarker.fill = am4core.color("#ff0000");
    mapMarker.fillOpacity = 0.8;
    mapMarker.horizontalCenter = "middle";
    mapMarker.verticalCenter = "bottom";
    var marker = imageSeries.mapImages.create();
    marker.latitude = country.lat;
    marker.longitude = country.long;


    setTimeout( () => {
      this.Animate = this.mChart.zoomToGeoPoint({latitude:country.lat,longitude:country.long},25,true)
    }, 100);

    marker.events.on("inited", function(event){
      animateBullet(event.target);
    })

    function animateBullet(obj) {
      let animation = obj.animate([{ property: "scale", from: 1, to: 3 }, { property: "opacity", from: 0, to: 1 }], 1000, am4core.ease.circleOut);
      animation.events.on("animationended", function(event){
        animateBullet(event.target.object);
      })
    }

  }
```